# Ul Li Side By Side For Language Translation

Tags: html, css

I asked a while back for tips on doing divs side by side. However, I actually figured out on my own a method to have text side by side by using ul li, and I'm really fond of it. It looks good, is mobile friendly, and works on all modern browsers. The problem though, is if I'm using this for huge amounts of text, for example, a story on one side and a translated version on the other side, will this have horrible implications for search engines!? After all, they're inclined to see li as lists not as huge text/paragraphs which is generally put in p.

If you're curious, I'll put my code here:

CSS:

```
div {
background: #fff;
border: 2px solid;
margin: 0;
overflow: auto;
padding: 1%;
text-align: left;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
li.halfa {
float: left;
width: 49.5%;
}
li.halfb {
float: left;
width: 49.5%;
}
li.space {
float: left;
width: 1%;
}
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
<ul>
<li class="halfa">english
<li class="space">&nbsp;
<li class="halfb">chinese
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: _“inclined to see li as lists not as huge text/paragraphs which is generally put in p”_ – you can use paragraphs _inside_ list items …

Comment: @ScottRickman Yes. "will this have horrible implications for search engines!?"

Comment: @CBroe Thanks! What effect might that have for search engines though? Will the p inside a li override a search engine's inclination to interpret it as lists?